# MxCalloc and MxFree with OpenMP results double free or corruption

Tags: c++, c, matlab, openmp, mex

The problem involves a large amount of code so I'll try to hopefully just give an idea of whats going on with a some example code. If there is something I've seemed to have left out  please comment and I'll add more. Anyway, I have an an object with a method that uses openMP:

```
#pragma omp parallel 
{  
int num_thread = omp_get_thread_num(); 

// This function will allocate and deallocate memory through Mxcalloc and MxFree before returning
foo.get_foo(num_thread);
}
```

The `foo` class has been defined in another file (that file was compiled with a `-C` flag) and is compiled and linked with the object that uses openMP. It allocates and deallocates memory with two methods:

```
void foo::alloc(const int &h, const int &w) {
if (value == NULL) {
        width = w;
        height = h;
        value = (double *)mxCalloc(h*w,sizeof(double));
    } else {
        mexPrintf("Memory has already been allocated when attempting to alloc.\n");
    }
}


void foo::free() {
    if (value != NULL) {
        width = 0;
        height = 0;
        mxFree(value);
        value = NULL;
    } else {
        mexPrintf("Memory has not been allocated yet when attempting to free.\n");  
    }
}
```

The code runs perfectly fine single threaded. However, when run with multiple threads, I get the following error:

```
*** glibc detected *** /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: double free or     corruption (out): 0x00007f4118019d20 ***
*** glibc detected *** /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x00007f4101120541 ***
*** glibc detected *** /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: double free or corruption (out): 0x00007f412c011260 ***
*** glibc detected *** /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x00007f4101120541 ***
```

Now, if I delete all the `free` calls (which subsequently deletes all the `mxFree` calls), and recompile/rerun the code, it seems to work fine (I find this very strange because the call to `mxFree` only occurs if the pointer isn't void - so I have no idea what the problem is). So I've narrowed it down to the fact the `mxFree` calls are not thread safe.

I also tried to add a `critical` section as shown below:

```
#pragma omp parallel 
{                  
int num_thread = omp_get_thread_num();

// This function will allocate and deallocate memory through Mxcalloc and MxFree before returning
#pragma omp critical
{
    foo.get_foo(num_thread);
}
}
```

And the code still doesn't work and results in similar error message. So my question is: is `mxFree` and `mxCalloc` completely nonthread safe- in that they only work when called by a single thread, and even if called independently (guaranteed by the `critical` section) by other threads the functions will still fail? I'd appreciate any tips or suggestions. I was thinking about maybe replacing the mxCalloc calls with just `std::vectors` and `resize` but I'd like to know whats going on first before changing a bunch of code around.

**UPDATE**
I just went through my code and used vectors with `resize` in place of the `mxCalloc` and `mxFree` and that fixed all the problems I was having. Just for future reference, absolutely avoid the MEX API in any parallelized regions. Even if you use a `critical` section, it still causes crashes for my linux system. The problem was actually masked for a while because this issue didn't occur on my laptop which uses Windows 7.

Comment: `foo` is only a single object.  That means you have a single storage location for the memory block.  Multiple threads will all use that same storage location and create the problem.  Do you want multiple foo objects, one per thread?  Do you want a single memory allocation, with multiple threads working on different parts of the object?

Comment: @Peter Probably should have specified, but there's one `foo` object per thread.

Comment: Actually, to be more specific, if there are three threads, there are three copies of the `foo` allocated outside the parallel region, and then the thread number is passed as an argument to foo to determine which thread has access to what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [C MEX API is not thread-safe](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101658-is-it-possible-to-start-new-threads-from-a-c-mex-file).  According to the MathWorks Support Team:

> Since the MEX API is not thread safe, no MEX API functions can be used in the spawned threads...

However, it seems that *some* MEX API functions [have been made thread-safe](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/explicit-multi-threading-in-matlab-part3), like `mexErrMsgIdAndTxt`.  It seems that dynamic memory allocation is still on the black list.

Instead of `mxMalloc` and `mxCalloc`, use `malloc` and `calloc` (or `new` and `delete[]`).

Comment: Even if used in a critical section? I'll read the link in greater detail now but I figured I'd ask if you know directly.

Comment: @jucestain Probably not then. I don't think concurrency is the issue. The rule is that you can't use any of the MEX API functions (`mx*` and `mex*` functions) inside of a spawned thread.  But, it's worth a try!

Comment: Chappjc, I think you might be right. I'm going to rewrite it anyway to avoid any `mx*` `mex*` calls in parallel regions just to be super safe. I  remember trying to do this with a waitbar a little while back and even in a critical sections it still failed... Might be better to just avoid the API all together in parallel regions as you suggest. I'm going to wait a little bit to see if anymore answers pop up but I have a feeling you're correct. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I'm not even sure if allocating space through STL vectors (or even `malloc` for that sake) is thread safe... Got my work cut out for me this weekend lol.

Comment: @jucestain Regarding thread-safety: http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=1795 and http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/explicit-multi-threading-in-matlab-part1#li-comment-315200.  However, you can certainly use vectors and dynamic allocation (`malloc`, `new`, etc.) in threads.  No problem there. Just clean up when each thread rejoins.